# Sync endpoint not returning data on recurring events moved out of date range

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

This is in regards to the calendar ['Sync Events' endpoint for Office365, V1.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#sync-events)

*Problem*: Given this endpoint, you must request for a delta of changes since the last sync. I'll call this the 'sync window' (the time between the start and end times in the query).

**Scenario 1:**

1. A single-instance event is created in the middle of the sync window.
2. The event is seen by the delta sync as being created.
3. On office365, the user moves the event to be outside the sync window (before or after the start/end dates).
4. On next delta sync, we receive a 'delete' event for the single instance event.

This makes sense - as far as the sync is concerned, that event is no longer in the sync window and we get an indication to remove it from our view.

**Scenario 2:**

1. A recurring event is created that has a start date before the start of the sync window, but has instances which occur inside the sync window.
2. The event is seen by the delta sync as being created, with instances that span from the start of the sync window onwards.
3. On Office365, the user changes the end-date of the recurring event to also be before the start of the sync window. That is - the recurrence now only occurs outside of the sync window and no occurrences happen inside the requested date range.
4. **On next delta sync, there is no data returned**

**The problem is that as the API consumer, I have no way to know that I should no longer be displaying events for the recurring event inside of the requested range. This behaviour seems to differ from that of the single instance events.**

Any information on whether or not this is intended behaviour would be helpful. The only alternative that I see is to query for each recurring event that we've ever encountered in the sync, but this is extremely undesirable.